Updating innerHTML
So, I'm just learning JS and trying to write a basic game using HTML/JS. I can't figure out how to update the score text.
I have a variable, "score", and a paragraph tag with the class "scoretext". I made a button, and I want to have it add 1 to the score when it is pressed. I have an onclick that says "score += 1" but I am unsure to to get the scoretext to update with the new score when the button is pressed.
Code:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

</style>
    </head>
<body>
<p id="scoretext"></p>
<script> 
var score = 0;
document.getElementById("scoretext").innerHTML = score; 
</script> 
<button onclick="score += 1;">Click</button> 
</body>
</html>




You already know that it's the innerHTML property that you need to change. What did you try? What happened?

This is my code so far:



If you want to change only the text content, you can try using .innerText.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText

Well yes, you only change the innerHTML at the start when score is 0. If you want to update the text when the variable's value changes you have to do it again.

You could just create a button that increases a score variable and then set the element to that score value.


<html>
<body>
  <h1 class="scoretext">Score: 0</h1>
  <button onclick="change()">Click Me!</button>
<script defer>
score = 0
function change(){
score++;
  document.getElementsByClassName('scoretext')[0].innerText = "Score: " + score;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>



